# $\lVert a \rVert = 1 = \lVert a^{-1} \rVert \Rightarrow a^* = a^{-1}$

Tags: functional-analysis, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

More rigorously, let $A$ be a unital $C^*$-algebra. I'm trying to prove that for $a$ ∈ Inv($A$), $$\lVert a \rVert = 1 = \lVert a^{-1} \rVert \Rightarrow a^* = a^{-1}.$$
To this end, I have already proved the following:

— the absolute value $|a|$ of $a$ constructed using the functional calculus is invertible if $a$ is;

— the element $u := a|a|^{-1}$ is unitary.

This begs the question: in our case, can we always find $b ∈ A$ such that $a = b|b|^{-1}$? If so, I have proved that $a$ is unitary. But perhaps this is not the right way to go about this at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By assumption $\|a^*a\|=1$ and $\|a^{-1}(a^{-1})^*\|=1.$ Thus $\|(a^*a)^{-1}\|=1.$ The element $b=a^*a$ is positive, invertible and $\|b\|=\|b^{-1}\|=1.$ Therefore the spectrum of $b$ is contained in $(0,1].$ We have $$\sigma(b^{-1})=\{t^{-1}\,:\, t\in \sigma(b)\}\subset [1,\infty )$$ As $\|b^{-1}\|=1$ the spectrum of $b$ must be  equal $\{1\}.$ In that case $b=e$ thus $a^*a=e.$

Comment: Ah yes, this is one thing I couldn't prove: why do we have $\lVert a^{-1} (a^{-1})^*\rVert = 1$? It's not of the form $\lVert x^*x \rVert$, so we can't use the $C^*$ identity.. Using the submultiplicativity of the norm, we only get '≤ 1'.

Comment: In a $C^*$-algebra there holds $\|b^*\|=\|b\|.$ Therefore $\|(a^{-1})^*\|=\|a^{-1}\|=1.$ Taking $x=(a^{-1})^*$ gives $\|a^{-1}(a^{-1})^*\|=\|x^*x\|=\|x\|^2=1.$

Comment: I figured it out :). Should we note that the proof for $aa^* = e$ is similar? Or is it automatic?

Comment: $aa^*=a(a^*a)a^{-1}=aa^{-1}=e $

Answer (score 1):

Using Gelfand-Neimark we may assume that $A$ is a subalgebra of $B(H)$, for some Hilbert space $H$.  Then, for every $\xi $ in $H$,
we have
$$
  \|a(\xi )\|\leq  \|\xi \| = \|a^{-1}(a(\xi ))\|\leq   \|a(\xi )\|.
  $$
So equality holds throughout and hence $a$ is an isometry, clearly also surjective.  Therefore $a$ is unitary.

Comment: Thanks, but we haven't covered GN yet, so I wanted to do it without.

Comment: No problem.  Ryszard's answer is certainly the most standard one, but I thought a different perspective would be worth it.